# More efficient way of writing this as part of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that will hide multiple IDs at once. As I will be getting into 50 or so IDs that will need to be hidden for any given function, I don't want to have unnecessary code. I have something like below, but there must be a way to combine all these lines in to one, no?

```
document.getElementById("aMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("aList").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bList").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("cMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("cList").style.display = "none";
```

Ok, thanks everyone.  Showing my updated code below. It's not working, as I am sure I am doing something wrong. The goal is to have a function that shows 2 elements that are identified by ID and hide all of the other IDs at the same time:

```
function zShowHideRest() {
    var zOther = ["aMap", "aList", "bMap", "bList", "cMap", "cList"];
    zOther.forEach.getElementById().style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("zMap").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("zList").style.display = "block";
}
```

Am I in the ballpark or is what I did way off?

Comment: Use an array of IDs, then [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I am new to Javascript though, and don't know what that means/how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through buttons and avoid repetition in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757965/how-to-loop-through-buttons-and-avoid-repetition-in-javascript)

Comment: Not sure it's the same... I want to have these elements be affected by something, not to affect something

Comment: It doesn’t matter what specifically you want to _do_ with the elements. You asked how to write this code in a shorter way. The basic way is exactly the same.

Comment: ok, thank you. sorry, as I am new to this I don't really know what I am talking about

Comment: Stop using IDs entirely. As you can see, they create brittle solutions that don't scale. Instead, simply assign a common class to each of the elements that will need to be hidden/shown and then loop over that collection to hide/show them.

Comment: thanks. but they all have to be addressed separately when it is their turn to be hidden. that's why I used IDs (in other words they can't have a common class). Unless there is a way for me to say "hide every element tagged with this class except this one"?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of the IDs in an array and iterate over them using a for of or forEach loop.

```
const arr = [your list of ids];
for(const a of arr) {
 document.getElementById(a).style.display = "none";
}
```

```
const arr = [your list of ids];
arr.forEach((a) => {
 document.getElementById(a).style.display = "none";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop helps reduce repeated code:

```js
const ids = ["aMap","aList","bMap","bList","cMap","cList"];

ids.forEach(
  function(id) {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I think this may be something that will help. I am going to try this. Thank you and thank you to all who have replied. I will report back later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("aMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("aList").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bList").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("cMap").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("cList").style.display = "none";

// method of array of id REF Sebastian Simon

let arrID = ["aMap", "aList", "bMap", "bList", "cMap", "cList",]

// method 1 for loop

    for (var i = 0; i < arrID.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(arrID[i]).style.display = "none";
    };

// method 2 for loop

    arrID.forEach((id) => {
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    });

    // arrow function not working any of IE

// my suggest

// give your elements same class example:"hide"

document.getElementsByClassName("hide").style.display = "none"; 

quickFix: you either use for loop but using class name makes without array of id but i have array of elements which is has classname hide

let elementsHasHide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
for (var i = 0; i < elementsHasHide.length; i++) {
    elementsHasHide[i].style.display="hide"
}
```

Comment: this is also helpful

Comment: @SebastianSimon oh i see. too Much jquery messes my vanilla script you how jquery works hha sorry i all fix it

Answer (score -1):

You should use Class instead of ID.

```
var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ids_list'),
        i = 0,
        l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
```

or

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')
    for (var i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
     list[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="ids_list" id="aMap"></div>
<div class="ids_list" id="aList"></div>
<div class="ids_list" id="bMap"></div>
<div class="ids_list" id="bList"></div>
<div class="ids_list" id="cMap"></div>
<div class="ids_list" id="cList"></div>
```

Just update js